# tensorflow 2.0 keras training with ImageDataGenerator + flow_from_directory + tf.data.Dataset gives "shape" related error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to wrap my generator into tf.data.Dataset (just to learn about this).
Here's my snippet. Hope someone can spot what I did wrong.

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

gen = img_gen.flow_from_directory(data_path, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            lambda: gen,
            output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
            output_shapes = ([32, 224, 224, 3], [32, 6]),
)

model.fit(dataset, 
          steps_per_epoch = gen.n // 32, 
          epochs=10)
```

ValueError: `generator` yielded an element of shape (11, 224, 224, 3) where an element of shape (32, 224, 224, 3) was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I "appeared" to resolve this if I changed this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: gen,
    output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32),
    # output_shapes = ([32, 224, 224, 3], [32, 6]),
    output_shapes = ([None, 224, 224, 3], [None, 6]),
)
```

i.e. Instead of explicit batch size of 32 in this bit of code, I replaced it with None. It apparently no longer complain about (11, 224, 224, 3), the remaining bit of batch. But is there a way for the dataset to sample 32 even at the end? just roll over onto the "beginning" of the train set. Something is still fishy to me.

I kicked off the .fit, and it is apparently working, loss going down and accuracy going up every epoch.

If someone has better way or explanations, please let me know.

Comment: Specifying None for the batch dimension in the output shape is the way to go. Alternatively, you could call `.batch()` on the Dataset with `skip_remainder=True`.